# Uso de chunk en laravel me retorna null

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando utilizar chunk de laravel para traer una cierta de cantidad de registros y `mapearlos`.

```
Message::chunk(100, function ($message) {
            foreach ($message as $msg) {
               dd($msg);
            }
        });
```

El problema es que no me retorna nada utilizando `dd($msg)` o `response()->json($msg)`
Intente utilizar `->get()` y me trae los resultados de manera exitosa.

¿Alguien sabe que esta ocurriendo? estoy utilizando `laravel` 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Falta obtener los datos y despues mapearlos.

```
Message::get()->chunk(100)->map(function ($mesage) {
 dd($message);
});
```